# This window doesn't open when click button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I create button command method to open another window in wpf,c#

This is my method

```
private void fn_cancel(object obj)
    {
        var windows = Application.Current.Windows;
        foreach (Window item in windows)
        {
            if (item.Name == "passwordReset")
                item.Close();
        }

        loginwindow objlog = new loginwindow();
        objlog.Show();
    }
```

in this method "passwordReset" window will close and after that loginwindow doesn't open! The problem in
`loginwindow objlog = new loginwindow();
            objlog.Show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you call `Close()` for current window where code is executed. If that is the main window, this terminates the application before the new window is shown.

Try open new window before closing the current.

```csharp
private void fn_cancel(object obj)
{
    loginwindow objlog = new loginwindow();
    objlog.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the window named "passwordReset" is the main window. While possible, it would make sense to clarify that with the asker.